# How do you use the Monster Gold Medal?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

I have a "Monster Gold Medal" that states "Can fight 7 monsters in battle".  I've equipped it onto one of the party members.  I can still only fight 5 monsters in battle. Is there something else that needs to be done? Does every member of the party have to have one equipped?

Comment: I was fighting 7 at a time before getting it. I don't know if that's something which has changed between January and now.

Answer (score 1):

The `Monster Gold Medal` is a Lv. 20 item that's dropped by the Swamp Monster in Dead End Swamp. Its effects are `+ 5% Gold on Battle, +2% Item Find`

The item that lets you fight 7 monsters in a battle is the `BK Crown` which costs 8 gold which you buy from `The Shop` (look at the top left corner of your screen for The Shop button).

The BK Crown looks like this:

[image]